# Angular2 Child Routes stopping page loading

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm fairly new to Angular2 and am trying to get to grips with routing, and in particular child routing.

I have based my application off the [Angular2-seed project](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed) and am trying to setup the routing. My routes are encapsulated within functional modules as I expect to have many functional areas to my application. For brevity I have omitted the module imports, it can be assumed that they are correct as the app loads.

app.component.ts

```
RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', component: HomeComponent, as: 'Home' },
  { path: '/area1/...', component: Area1Component, as: 'Area1' },
  { path: '/area2/...', component: Area2Component, as: 'Area2' },
])
```

area1.component.ts

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/...', component: Area1Component, as: 'Area1' },
    { path: '/function1', component: Function1Component, as: 'Function1' },
])
```

area2.component.ts

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/...', component: Area2Component, as: 'Area2' },
    { path: '/function2', component: Function2Component, as: 'Function2' },
])
```

my navigation is defined as follows

```
<nav>
    <a [routerLink]="['Home']">HOME</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['Area1', 'Function1']">A NICE FUNCTION</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['Area2', 'Function2']">ANOTHER NICE FUNCTION</a>
</nav>
```

If I run the application normally and navigate the menu structures all is fine, however if I refresh the page or allow browser sync to do the same when I am within any of the child routes the tab hosting the application spins up to 100% cpu usage. I have not been able to work out where the code is spinning and would appreciate any pointers that I may have missed in setting up the routing.

Comment: `as` is deprecated, use `name` instead. What's the purpose of the `/...` routes? Looks like there are more child routes that you omitted in your question. I guess this needs a Plunker to reproduce?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer shame about as, I think it's more readable than name. As for the /... routes I thought they where needed for the child routing, a misunderstanding of reading examples. I've removed them and now the routing works perfectly. Can you put your comment as an answer and i'll mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `as` is deprecated, use name instead.
- `/...` at the end of the route path indicates to the router that there are more child routes. Without `/...` they are terminal routes. From the code in your question it looks like there are no further child routes therefore these routes are rendundant.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use nested routes you can use the `children` property, as described [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html):

```
{
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '' },
        { path: 'contacts/:id',  component: ContactsComponent },
    ]
}
```

and in your ContactsComponent template, add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`